# Create two dropdowns in dashboardSidebar based on column of input

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to make two dropdowns on the sidebar, one for each unique string in the `RNAType`  column in my df.t data frame. One dropdown should be named `MicroRNA` and the other `snRNA` and the choices within the dropdown should be taken from the column `miRNA`. I have provided an example how this is done when I only have one group, the MicroRNA, however, I don't know how to add two `dashboardSidebar` based on the column input

library(survival)
library(survminer)

```
   df.t <-  structure(list(miRNA = c("hsa-let-7f-3p", "hsa-let-7d-3p", "hsa-let-7c-3p", 
"hsa-let-7g-3p", "hsa-let-7g-3p", "hsa-let-7i-3p"), RNAType = c("MicroRNA", 
"MicroRNA", "MicroRNA", "snRNA", "snRNA", "snRNA"), Status = c("1", 
"0", "1", "1", "1", "1"), TimeDiff = c("213", "1313", "2442", 
"1313", "1212", "2213"), value = c("10.3", "4", "3", "2.4", "5.4", 
"4.3")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

ui.miRNA <- dashboardPage(
        # Application title
        dashboardHeader(title=h4(HTML("Plot"))),
        dashboardSidebar(
            selectInput("MicroRNA", "miRNA", choices = unique( df.t$miRNA))),
        dashboardBody(
            sliderInput("obs", "Quantiles",
                        min = 0, max = 1, value = c(0.4, 0.8)
            ),
            tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("myplot", width = "400px", height = "300px"))
            )
        )
    )
```

My server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
            data_selected <- reactive({
        req(input$MicroRNA)
        filter(df.t, miRNA %in% input$MicroRNA)
    })
            output$myplot <- renderPlot({
        lower_value <- input$obs[1]
        upper_value <- input$obs[2]
        fitSurv <-   survfit(Surv(TimeDiff, Status) ~ cut(value, quantile(value, probs = c(0, lower_value, upper_value)), include.lowest=TRUE),data = data_selected())
        
        new_env <- environment()
        new_env$value <- data_selected()$value
        new_env$TimeDiff <- data_selected()$TimeDiff
        new_env$Status <- data_selected()$Status
        new_env$lower_value <- lower_value
        new_env$upper_value <- upper_value
                    ggsurvplot(fitSurv, 
                   new_env)
                              
        
        
    }    )
}
```

Comment: from which package do you got the `survfit` function from? Could you please add the packages you need to run the scripts with `library()`?

Comment: library(survival), although I have not provided TimeDiff and Status in this example.

Comment: Updated input with TimeDiff and Status and value

Comment: I think the format in your data frame isnt correct. Should `TimeDiff` be numeric and `Status` logical?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filtered the column RNAType for MicroRNA and snRNA and created the dropdowns based on the unique values of miRNA. You can then use both input values to create 2 separate plots with the filtered dataframes.

Your reactive `data_selected` has no use in my view

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(survival)
library(survminer)

df.t <- structure(list(
  miRNA = c("hsa-let-7f-3p", "hsa-let-7d-3p", "hsa-let-7c-3p", "hsa-let-7g-3p", "hsa-let-7g-3p", "hsa-let-7i-3p"),
  RNAType = c("MicroRNA", "MicroRNA", "MicroRNA", "snRNA", "snRNA", "snRNA"),
  Status = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
  TimeDiff = c(213, 1313, 2442, 1313, 1212, 2213),
  value = c(10.3, 4, 3, 2.4, 5.4, 4.3)
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


ui.miRNA <- dashboardPage(
  # Application title
  dashboardHeader(title=h4(HTML("Plot"))),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput(
      "MicroRNA", "miRNA",
      choices = df.t %>% filter(RNAType == "MicroRNA") %>% distinct(miRNA) %>% pull(miRNA)
    ),
    selectInput(
      "snRNA", "snRNA",
      choices = df.t %>% filter(RNAType == "snRNA") %>% distinct(miRNA) %>% pull(miRNA)
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    sliderInput("obs", "Quantiles",
                min = 0, max = 1, value = c(0.4, 0.8)
    ),
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot",
               plotOutput("myplot1", width = "400px", height = "300px"),
               plotOutput("myplot2", width = "400px", height = "300px"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$myplot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$MicroRNA)
    df.t.sub <- df.t %>% filter(RNAType == "MicroRNA" & miRNA %in% input$MicroRNA)
    lower_value <- input$obs[1]
    upper_value <- input$obs[2]
    fitSurv <-   survfit(Surv(TimeDiff, Status) ~ cut(value, quantile(value, probs = c(0, lower_value, upper_value)), include.lowest=TRUE),data = df.t.sub)

    new_env <- environment()
    new_env$value <- df.t.sub$value
    new_env$TimeDiff <- df.t.sub$TimeDiff
    new_env$Status <- df.t.sub$Status
    new_env$lower_value <- lower_value
    new_env$upper_value <- upper_value
    ggsurvplot(fitSurv, new_env)
  })

  output$myplot2 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$snRNA)
    df.t.sub <- df.t %>% filter(RNAType == "snRNA" & miRNA %in% input$snRNA)
    lower_value <- input$obs[1]
    upper_value <- input$obs[2]
    fitSurv <-   survfit(Surv(TimeDiff, Status) ~ cut(value, quantile(value, probs = c(0, lower_value, upper_value)), include.lowest=TRUE),data = df.t.sub)

    new_env <- environment()
    new_env$value <- df.t.sub$value
    new_env$TimeDiff <- df.t.sub$TimeDiff
    new_env$Status <- df.t.sub$Status
    new_env$lower_value <- lower_value
    new_env$upper_value <- upper_value
    ggsurvplot(fitSurv, new_env)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui.miRNA, server)
```

The first plot generates an error because it contains only one row where `lower_value` and `upper_value` are identical. Adding some more data should solve the problem. To remove the error you could also add some conditions to `req()`

Comment: That worked perfect for creating the Sidebars. No I am wondering how to create two plots, one for  each "selectInput". I have attached the plotting function I use for one plot.

Comment: Updated my post regarding your updated question including the plots